# How do I proxy esm packages?

Tags: esm

When ESM is installed, it updates the source list for apt, such as:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-apps.list
deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu bionic-apps-security main
# deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu bionic-apps-security main
deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu bionic-apps-updates main
# deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu bionic-apps-updates main
```

And I would like to use a JFrog-based proxy server instead of going directly to esm.ubuntu.com. This works fine for me for normal packages, but once I modify this file, the pro status switches to "disabled".

```
pro status
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS    DESCRIPTION
cc-eal           yes       disabled  Common Criteria EAL2 Provisioning Packages
cis              yes       disabled  Security compliance and audit tools
esm-apps         yes       disabled  Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes       disabled  Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
fips             yes       disabled  NIST-certified core packages
fips-updates     yes       disabled  NIST-certified core packages with priority security updates
livepatch        yes       enabled   Canonical Livepatch service
ros              yes       disabled  Security Updates for the Robot Operating System
ros-updates      yes       disabled  All Updates for the Robot Operating System
```

So - how can I modify the sources.list without triggering an error within pro?

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* earlier this year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

Answer (score 0):

ESM repos require authentication.  You probably need to configure your proxy with the credentials configured in `/etc/apt/auth.conf.d` by *ubuntu-advantage*.